# replace string part only in textbox vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all just want to ask if it is possible to replace or delete a part of string in textbox? instead of replacing or removing the whole string it will just remove part of it only . The program will be as below procedure.

1. A user will key in string or text in a textbox example abc123cd
2. in an excel cells have a default value of abc and cd . Let we say abc is in A1 and cd in A2.
3. Then those default value in A1 and A2 will remove abc and cd in abc123cd. The output will be 123 in the same textbox. it means before it is abc123cd , after clicking commnad button the result will be 123 only in the same textbox.

Below is my sample vba program. But obviously I cannot find the way to fix the issue just to suit my requirements. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim myFind As String
    Dim myReplace1 As String
    Dim myReplace2 As String
    Dim sExportFolder, sFN
    Dim rArticleName As Range
    Dim rDisclaimer As Range
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim oTxt As Object

    'Specify name of Sheet with list of replacements
    Set myReplaceSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Assuming list of replacement start in column A on row 2, find last entry in list
    myLastRow = myReplaceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop through all list of replacments
    For myRow = 2 To myLastRow
        'Get find and replace values (from columns A and B)
        myFind = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "A")
        myReplace1 = myReplaceSheet.Cells(myRow, "B")

        'Start at top of data sheet and do replacements
        myDataSheet.Activate
        Range("A2").Select

        'Ignore errors that result from finding no matches
        On Error Resume Next

        'Do all replacements 
        With TextBox1
            .Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace1, LookAt:=xlPart, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
              ReplaceFormat:=False
        End With
    Next myRow
End Sub
```

Comment: which one is the textbox that has the full userentered string?

Comment: And if I'm not totally wrong, you're missing something like .value after .Cells(myRow, X)

Comment: Hi Kathara . thanks for your reply . Actually its in Do all replacement comment but I cannot figure out what should be the syntax i will be using . I just tried to search and created the sample program. Actually that program is working if i will use cell to input or key in values but what I want is to use textbox instead of cell for input and any replacement will be done in textbox itself.

Comment: What kind of textbox? Active-x or Form controls?

Comment: the textbox should be in the userform and it will be a multiline textbox.

Comment: multiline? How long will the string be that has to be replaced? Do all occurances of the replacements have to be eliminated in the entered string?

Comment: Hi Kathara . The length of string vary and not the same in every input . it Can be example abc123cd, abcd23456def or cd3456ab.

Comment: But why would you use a multiline textbox then?

Comment: its a multiple entry of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just changing the value inside the textbox? For example:

```
TextBox1.Value = VBA.Replace(TextBox1.Value, myFind, myReplace1)
```

Comment: Hi Slaqr. Thanks for this I will test the code and let you know . Thank you.

Comment: The .Replace method is correct but if I understood right it would be VBA.Replace(TextBox1.Value, myReplace1, "")

Comment: Hi Slaqr your code is working . really thanks for the help.